# Can you train yourself to need less sleep

Tags: sleep

Title says it all, got the idea from this old answer on stack exchange

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3375

The user suggests that it is possible to train yourself to need less sleep.

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer now, but there is a type of polyphasic sleep that supposedly allows you to sleep something like 20 minutes every 4 hours. I read several things about it years back, but don't personally know anyone who's tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer that you are referring to](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3375/33155) is mistaken about biphasic/polyphasic sleep. It claims:

> It *is* possible to train the human body into needing much less sleep.

However, nowhere does the [first link provided for evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biphasic_and_polyphasic_sleep) claim that biphasic/polyphasic sleep makes the body *need* less sleep. The claim is that it's possible to better recover in less time in order to maintain performance when undergoing sleep deprivation, which is not the same thing at all as *needing less*.

The closing lines of the [last link provided for evidence](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2006-09-probing.html) actually make that clear:

> "… there is no denying the effects of sleep deprivation. And training the body to sleep less is not a viable option." Nothing matches a good night's sleep.